# How to prevent Vivaldi from randomly focusing the URL field instead of the autofocus text input after AutoHotKey-opening it?

Tags: windows-10, keyboard-shortcuts, autohotkey, vivaldi

I have this AutoHotKey hotkey:

```
F2::
Run, "http://127.0.0.1/test/"
KeyWait, F2
return
```

Thus, when I press the `F2` button on my keyboard, it opens the URL `http://127.0.0.1/test/` in my Web browser, meaning Vivaldi.

If Vivaldi is already open, it opens it in a new tab and focuses it.
If Vivaldi is not already open, it opens Vivaldi and the URL as the one and only tab.

The `index.html` page, which is valid HTML, just has a simple text field in the body as so:

```
<div><input spellcheck="true" type="text" name="phrase" id="phrase" size="48" tabindex="1" autofocus></div>
```

*Most* of the time, this works. However, "sometimes", and I cannot for the life of me figure out why it happens (in spite of trying it over and over and over), the input is not autofocused. Instead, Vivaldi focuses the URL field instead, and thus I start typing in the URL field instead of the text input on the page.

It's difficult to explain just how annoying this is, since I use this mechanism about ten thousand times per day, every day. I've tried so many times, but whenever I try to make it happen, I just cannot reproduce it. It simply happens when I least expect it, for seemingly no reason.

It does not depend on whether or not Vivaldi is already running. It also doesn't *seem* to matter how quickly I start typing after pressing the `F2` button, although I can't say for sure.

I previously used Pale Moon in the same manner and this did not happen there, so it must be somehow related to Vivaldi. (No, switching back to Pale Moon is not an option.)

Could you fellow superusers please tell me some solution to this to save my sanity?

Answer (score 1):

I know this scenario from various AHK automations. But instead of finding answer to what is focused and why, it is beneficial to **work around** the issue:

After expecting an open page, do not think about default focus on a page control (like that text input). Instead, focus the URL explicitly (using <kbd>F8</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> [↗Vivaldi help](https://help.vivaldi.com/desktop/shortcuts/keyboard-shortcuts/)) and then send expected number of <kbd>Tab</kbd> keys to focus target form control inside the web page.

If you have control over the web page content, then there is even more reliable solution: Adjust the HTML to contain [keyboard shortcut which focuses your input box](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_accesskey.asp) (`accesskey` atrribute). Then, let the AHK send that combination. Example: If you assigned `accesskey="a"` to the input box, send <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> ([↗Vivaldi help](https://help.vivaldi.com/desktop/shortcuts/webpage-access-key-shortcuts/)) to focus this input box.
Note: it is possible that before this will start working, it is needed to enable acess keys in Vivaldi – see the last hyperlink.

---

Edit:

Desperate solution *after* focusing URL bar, but a workable one:
Test focus on your field by moving its default value into clipboard.

1. Have a special default value in your input box, for example "X".
2. In AHK script, backup clipboard content (`ClipboardOld := ClipboardAll`).
3. In AHK, empty the clipboard. (`Clipboard =`)
4. In AHK, `Send {Tab}^x`  (move focus, then cut the selection)
5. Use ClipWait with timeout (`ClipWait ,,1`) to see whether the clipboard was populated and test if it contains your default value from step 1. (`If (Clipboard <> "X") ...`)
6. If yes, it means you have focused your field and your code can continue. If no, loop for the same attempt (step 4) a few times, then fail.
7. In any of the above cases, restore the clipboard content from backup and release the variable. (`Clipboard := ClipboardOld`, `ClipboardOld =`)

Comment: Yes, I control the page. And I added the accesskey attribute and verified that it works when I press Alt + Shift + a manually. But, as usual, whenever I try to make AutoHotKey do *anything whatsoever*, it **never** works: `Send {LShift}{LAlt}a` does nothing, and neither do the hundred other combinations I tried.

Comment: I just found this: `Combinations of three or more keys are not supported.` Great...

Comment: I also have now tried the Ctrl + L thing and then one Tab, but this ALSO only works "randomly". Nothing about AutoHotKey is solid and works every time. It's a flimsy POS. Sigh. I'm completely stuck now.

Comment: @Ike – First: Use `Send !+a` instead of `{LAlt}...`, this should work normally. Also, add a delay between Ctrl+L and Tab, for example `Sleep 500`. Not the best but it can help.

Comment: Regarding the clipboard hack: that won't work because it would clear my own clipboard contents, which are frequently what's immediately pasted into the form. (Unless I misunderstand what you mean. Trying the Send/Sleep thing now.)

Comment: `Send !+a` does nothing, with or without Sleep...

Comment: I don't understand how something so simple and basic can turn into rocket science. It's always like this. Sigh.

Comment: @Ike – Clipboard trick will work, because in step 2 we back up its content and in step 7 we restore it. So you have it back and you can paste it into input box if needed. Just perhaps perform another emptying followed by `ClipWait,,15` before the restoration, because large data on the clipbord may take longer to restore. If some AHK actions are occassionally missed, insert a delay. The issue of focus can be complicated and staying under the radar of ordinary users. This is why you find things like this quite often. I was able to see the same also in Chrome and Opera.

Comment: @Ike – yet another hack is to test a pixel for color. Either frame of URL bar or frame of input box etc. See which one changes its color on focus. Just use coordinates related to window client area so they will work regardless of window position. You get the point – clipboard test or pixel test or anything else – you need to get a fixed point which allows you to verify whether your control flow is going right. If no, repeat and if yes, just contine with further actions. Normally, you don't do this, you typically wait for a new window using WinWaitActive. Such waiting for sthg. is common in AHK